# how to call TurboVNC in lightdm.conf?

Tags: vnc, vncserver, lightdm

I am trying to change the [VNCserver] in lightdm.conf from TightVNC to TurboVNC
but after I finished the installation of TurboVNC, I must open it by /opt/TurboVNC/bin/vncserver instead of just the command "vncserver"

Is it possible to replace the tag[VNCserver] in lightdm.conf to become the TurboVNC?
Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend that you should add some information about your setup. What OS, what versions of TurboVNC and lightdm?

Comment: So what happens if you just call `vncserver`? Do you get your old VNC server then? What if you uninstall that? Otherwise, is `/opt/TurboVNC/bin/` in your `PATH` variable?